# Maven build for Spring boot Application for windows and linux platforms

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, spring-boot

I need to generate my spring boot application binaries for windows and linux platforms using Maven build.

I am planning to have two different application.properties for windows and linux i.e

- application-windows.properties
- application-linux.properties

and in the pom.xml I will have this

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <activatedProperties>windows</activatedProperties>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <properties>
        <activatedProperties>linux</activatedProperties>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Maven build will be triggered using Jenkins.But in this way I can have only one profile active at a time,So It will require two jenkins project for windows and linux.
Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Why you need different properties at build time?

Comment: I need to have different property value based on platform for e.g.
log dir in linux will be in /var/log/....
but in case of windows it will be different..

Comment: In my opinion such property files should not be part of the artefact which will be delivered. Such properties should be provided by the target system.

Comment: But I do not want to use any external property file.My property file will be the  part of the build jar.

Comment: Just provide both property files in your app (you shouldn't build different artifacts for different environments) then start your app with `--spring.profiles.active=<your-environment>` or create an `ApplicationInitializer` which sets.adds the active profile based on the detected environment.

Comment: Thanks, this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Profile should be chosen by giving build argument while starting the spring boot application.

`-Dspring.profles.active=$profile`

If you are using jenkins to start the application , just add an option to choose profile during job execution which can add parameter to application.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html